# getting results of BigQuery into memory on GC instance

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to pull data from a google BigQuery dataset into memory on a GC instance in the same region, but it's taking far too long.  A simple query with a single WHERE clause is taking 10 minutes to run.  I believe most of this 10 minutes is spent downloading the data from the BigQuery dataset to the GC instance, as when I run it from the CLI it runs in under 20 seconds.

CLI Example:

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM dataset.table where field1 = 'test'"
```

This takes about 20s and processes 2-6 GB

Python example:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset')
query = ("SELECT * FROM dataset.table where field1 = 'test'")
query_job = client.query(query)
```

This takes about 10 minutes.

Python API is [here](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html).

How can I quickly get data from BigQuery into memory on a GC instance?

Comment: This is weird as the CLI also uses Python behind its operations (even though it uses the googleapiclient library, the http requests behind it are just the same). Maybe it was some network issue you had, not sure (try running again to see how it goes). Also, did you run the CLI command in the GC instance or in a local host?

Comment: Something is wrong in your question. `query_job = client.query(query)` just insert job into bigquery - and return job_id that you can use lately to check status. Could you please show us full code with details where you reading result of query

Comment: The time should be almost the same. I have done several tests and for me it is the same. Did you run the both pieces of code several times? It would be better, as said by @AlexeyMaloletkin to see the entire code you are using. If you used a batch query or you were doing a lot of queries or you had network issues at that time could explain a difference in this sense but is difficult to say without more information.